# How can I turn Firebase listeners into observable map using data binding library?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-databinding

### TL; DR

Would it be possible to hide all [Firebase read and write operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) behind a [`ObservableMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableMap.html) as a [Facade Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)?

So all we would have to do would be:

```
User oldUser = map.put(user);
User newUser = map.get(primaryKey);
```

### Full Question

According to [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write), in order to write a value, I would have to define a resource path through a[`DatabaseReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) and set a value.

For example, if we had a [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) plain-text object, we would set it like:

```
mDatabase.child("users")
    .push()
    .setValue(user);
```

For reading the whole `users` tree, we would have to implement a [`ChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener). As soon as the new user be part of the tree, it would be received through [`onChildAdded`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener.html#onChildAdded(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot,%20java.lang.String)):

```
@Override
public void onChildChanged (DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
    Log.i(TAG, snapshot.getValue(User.class));
}
```

And finally for reading a specific user, we use a [`ValueEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener):

```
mDatabase.child("users")
    .child(primaryKey)
    .setValue(user)
    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Log.i(TAG, snapshot.getValue(User.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

So would be possible using an [`ObservableMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableMap.html) as a [Facade Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), hidding all [Firebase read and write operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL; DR

I combined [`ObservableArrayMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableArrayMap.html) and [`ChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) into a [**`FirebaseArrayMap`**](https://github.com/jpventura/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/data_binding/databinding/src/main/java/br/com/firebase/ui/databinding/FirebaseArrayMap.java).

A working [FirebaseUI-Android](https://github.com/jpventura/FirebaseUI-Android) example is available [here](https://github.com/jpventura/FirebaseUI-Android/commits/data_binding). Now all you have to do is:

```
// Remote updates immediately send you your view
map.addOnMapChangedCallback(mUserChangedCallback);

// Non blocking operation to update database
map.create(user);

// Local up-to-date cache
User user = map.get(primaryKey);
```

Remember to (un)register your [`OnMapChangedCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableMap.OnMapChangedCallback.html) in [`onResume`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) and [`onPause`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) in order to avoid memory leaking caused by [`ChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) remote updates.

### CRUD

First we need to create a *thesaurus* interface for [`Map`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html), i.e.:

```
public interface CRUD<K, V> {

    Task<V> create(V value);

    Task<V> create(K key, V value);

    Task<Void> createAll(SimpleArrayMap<? extends K, ? extends V> array);

    Task<Void> createAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map);

    V read(K key);

    Task<V> delete(K key);

    Task<Void> free();

}
```

This interface will be implemented by [`FirebaseArrayMap`](https://github.com/jpventura/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/data_binding/databinding/src/main/java/br/com/firebase/ui/databinding/FirebaseArrayMap.java), returning the *same values* that would be returned by [`Map`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html).

The methods are analogous to [`put`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)), [`putAll`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map%3C?%20extends%20K,%20?%20extends%20V%3E)) and [`get`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)), but instead of return values they return [`Tasks`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/Task) with those values (or exceptions). Example:

```
    @Override
    public Task<Void> createAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map) {
        Collection<Task<V>> tasks = new ArrayList<>(map.size());
        for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            tasks.add(create(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }
        return Tasks.whenAll(tasks);
    }

    @Override
    public V read(K key) {
        return get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Task<V> delete(K key) {
        final V oldValue = get(key);
        final Continuation<Void, V> onDelete = new Continuation<Void, V>() {
            @Override
            public V then(@NonNull Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
                task.getResult();
                return oldValue;
            }
        };
        return mDatabaseReference.child(key.toString())
            .setValue(null)
            .continueWith(onDelete);
    }
```

### ObservableArrayMap

We create an abstract [`FirebaseArrayMap`](https://github.com/jpventura/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/data_binding/databinding/src/main/java/br/com/firebase/ui/databinding/FirebaseArrayMap.java) extending [`ObservableArrayMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableArrayMap.html) and implementing both [`ChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) and [`CRUD`](https://github.com/jpventura/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/data_binding/databinding/src/main/java/br/com/firebase/ui/databinding/CRUD.java).

```
public abstract class FirebaseArrayMap<K extends Object, V> extends
    ObservableArrayMap<K, V> implements ChildEventListener, CRUD<K, V> {

    private final DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

    public abstract Class<V> getType();

    public FirebaseArrayMap(@NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        mDatabaseReference = databaseReference;
    }
```

The [`ChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) will use the super methods, turning the [`ObservableArrayMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableArrayMap.html) into a local cache.

Consequently, when a write operation is successfully completed (or a remote change happens), the [`ChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) will automatically update our [`Map`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html)

```
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage(), error.toException());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            super.put((K) snapshot.getKey(), snapshot.getValue(getType()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
        super.put((K)snapshot.getKey(), snapshot.getValue(getType()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        super.put((K)snapshot.getKey(), snapshot.getValue(getType()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        super.remove(dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }
```

### The Contract

The [`CRUD`](https://github.com/jpventura/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/data_binding/databinding/src/main/java/br/com/firebase/ui/databinding/CRUD.java) interface is required in order to not break [`Map`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html) contract. For example, [`put`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)) returns the previous value when a new value is inserted at the given position, but this operation is now **asynchronous**.

For writing operations, the hack here is using [`CRUD`](https://github.com/jpventura/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/data_binding/databinding/src/main/java/br/com/firebase/ui/databinding/CRUD.java) for *non blocking* and [`Map`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)) for *blocking* operations:

```
    @Override
    @WorkerThread
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        try {
            return Tasks.await(create(key, value));
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

### Data Binding

For free, now you also have [Android Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) for your [`Map`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html):

```
@Override
protected onCreate() {
    mUserMap = new UserArrayMap();
    mChangedCallback = new OnUserMapChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mUserMap.addOnMapChangedCallback(mChangedCallback);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mUserMap.removeOnMapChangedCallback(mChangedCallback);
    super.onPause();
}
```

and

```
static class OnUserMapChanged extends OnMapChangedCallback<FirebaseArrayMap<String, User>, String, User> {

    @Override
    public void onMapChanged(FirebaseArrayMap<String, User> sender, String key) {
        Log.e(TAG, key);
        Log.e(TAG, sender.get(key).toString());
    }

}
```

Remember to (un)register your callback in [`onResume`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) and [`onPause`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) in order to avoid memory leaking caused by [`ChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) updates.